# Таблица в html.Нужна помощь

Tags: html, html5

Помогите сделать хотя-бы 1 таблицу которая на фотке изображена
Я смог только так ,и не понимаю как в таблице сделать разные размеры ячеек,
и что бы одна ячейка находилась над другой

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML код таблицы, примеры</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td width="100px" heigh="300">1</td>
<br/>
<td width="200px" heigh="150">2</td>
<td width="100px" heigh="150">3</td>
<td width="100px" heigh="150">4</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно для этого воспользоваться атрибутами [colspan](http://htmlbook.ru/html/td/colspan) и [rowspan](http://htmlbook.ru/html/td/rowspan), которые объединяют ячейки по горизонтали и по вертикали, соответственно.

```css
table {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">1</td>
    <td colspan="2">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```